# «…Каренина(,) в придворном мундире с новою красною лентою через плечо»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Из «Анны Карениной»:

> — Нет. Вы взгляните на него, — сказал старичок, указывая расшитою шляпой на остановившегося в дверях залы с одним из влиятельных членов Государственного совета **Каренина в придворном мундире с новою красною лентою через плечо**.

[Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=110):

> Несогласованные определения, выраженные формами косвенных падежей существительных (чаще с предлогами), обособляются для выделения какого-либо признака или для усиления выражаемого ими значения: *Холоп, **в блестящем убранстве, с откидными назад рукавами,** разносил тут же разные напитки и съестное* (Г.).
>
> Обычно обособляются несогласованные определения, дополняющие или уточняющие представление о лице либо предмете, который сам по себе (без определения) достаточно конкретен, уже известен. В этой роли выступают имена собственные (они выделяют лицо-предмет из ряда подобных), названия лиц по степени родства, по занимаемому положению, профессии, должности, а также местоимения (указывают на лицо, уже известное из контекста).

Автор действительно постоянно обособляет такие конструкции, но здесь он почему-то этого не сделал. Почему? Что подразумевается под «выделения какого-либо признака или для усиления выражаемого ими значения» и почему здесь это не работает?

Comment: И не только Автор: «Лев Николаевич показывает преуспевающего царского сановника, Алексея Александровича Каренина в придворном мундире с красной лентой через плечо в момент примерки знаков только что полученного от императора ордена Александра Невского». 
(Орденский след в русской классической литературе и живописи. С. Коломнин)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   ...но здесь он почему-то этого не сделал. Почему?
```

Видимо, потому, что никакое уточнение здесь не нужно.

> Обычно обособляются несогласованные определения, дополняющие или
>   уточняющие представление о лице либо предмете, который сам по себе
>   (без определения) достаточно конкретен, уже известен.

Лев Толстой повествует о сцене, где над Алексеем Александровичем иронизируют, посмеиваются:
"Счастлив и доволен, как медный грош". Доволен, потому что получил орден Александра Невского за государственную службу: чиновники увидели Алексея Александровича в придворном мундире с красной лентой через плечо. Они знают, что от него ушла жена, а значит, карьера его окончена, а он этого не понимает, считает себя важным человеком.

**Каренин в придворном мундире с новою красною лентою через плечо** - это цельный образ, где лента ордена и Каренин нераздельны, поэтому определение не отделяется от определяемого слова. Уточнения здесь нет. Толстой очень чувствует русский язык, читая его тексты, нужно вдумываться, искать причины постановки знаков препинания или непостановки.